# Проблема с сохранением entity которая имеет связь many-tо-many

Tags: spring, hibernate, java-ee, spring-mvc

Проблема заключается в том, что при сохранении Item в спецификации добавляются id самых спецификаций. Более чем уверен что проблема в том, как я храню Item в ItemService, но если не получить лист спецификаций и не сохранить их, то получу :

> transientobjectexception: object references an unsaved transient
>   instance - save the transient instance beforequery flushing

Таблицы :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Entity Item связана со спецификациями связью many-to-many

```
@Entity
public class Item extends AbstractEntity{

    private String name;

    private BigDecimal price;

    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Producer producer; 

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Category category;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="specification_item",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_item"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_specification"))
    private List<Specification> specifications= new ArrayList<Specification>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="specificationDigital_item",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_item"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_specificationDigital"))
    private List<SpecificationDigital> specificationDigitals= new ArrayList<SpecificationDigital>();

    public Item(String name, BigDecimal price, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Item() {

    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Producer getProducer() {
        return producer;
    }

    public void setProducer(Producer producer) {
        this.producer = producer;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public List<Specification> getSpecifications() {
        return specifications;
    }

    public void setSpecifications(List<Specification> specifications) {
        this.specifications = specifications;
    }

    public List<SpecificationDigital> getSpecificationDigitals() {
        return specificationDigitals;
    }

    public void setSpecificationDigitals(List<SpecificationDigital> specificationDigitals) {
        this.specificationDigitals = specificationDigitals;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item [name=" + name + ", price=" + price + ", description=" + description + "]";
    }   

}
```

Item заполняю через эту форму, а спецификации выбираю через select

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12">
    <c:if test="${category ne null}">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <form:form class="form-horizontal" action="/admin/item" method="POST" modelAttribute="item">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                            <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="name" id="name"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Price</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                            <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="price" id="price"/>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <form:hidden value="${category.id}" path="category"/>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Producer</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                            <form:select class="form-control" path="producer" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id" items="${producers}"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                            <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="description" id="description"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <c:forEach items="${nameSpecifications}" var="nameSpecification">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">${nameSpecification.name}</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <form:select path="specifications" items="${nameSpecification.specifications}" itemLabel="specification" itemValue="id" class="form-control" multiple="false"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </c:forEach>

                    <c:forEach items="${nameSpecificationDigitals}" var="nameSpecificationDigital">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">${nameSpecificationDigital.name}</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                <form:select path="specificationDigitals" items="${nameSpecificationDigital.specificationDigitals}" itemLabel="specification" itemValue="id" class="form-control" multiple="false"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </c:forEach> 

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form:form>
            </div>
        </div>
</c:if>
</div>
</div>
```

Item добавляю через категорию.

```
<c:forEach items="${categories}" var="category">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">${category.name}</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"><a class="btn btn-success" href="/admin/category/add/nameOfSpecificationString/${category.id}">Add</a></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"><a class="btn btn-success" href="/admin/category/add/nameOfSpecificationDigital/${category.id}">Add</a></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"><a class="btn btn-success" href="/admin/item/add/${category.id}">Add</a></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4"><a class="btn btn-warning" href="/admin/category/update/${category.id}">update</a> 
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="/admin/category/delete/${category.id}">delete</a></div>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Specification editor

```
public class SpecificationEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport{

    private final SpecificationService specificationService;

    public SpecificationEditor(SpecificationService specificationService) {
        this.specificationService = specificationService;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Specification specification= specificationService.findOne(Long.valueOf(text));
        setValue(specification);
    }
}
```

Item service

```
@Service
public class ItemServiceImpl implements ItemService{

    @Autowired
    private ItemDAO itemDAO;

    @Autowired
    private SpecificationDigitalDAO specificationDigitalDAO;

    @Autowired
    private SpecificationDAO specificationDAO;

    @Override
    public void save(Item item) {
        List<SpecificationDigital> sds= item.getSpecificationDigitals();
        List<Specification> ss= item.getSpecifications();
        specificationDigitalDAO.save(sds);
        specificationDAO.save(ss);
        item.setSpecificationDigitals(sds);
        item.setSpecifications(ss);
        itemDAO.save(item);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Item> findAll() {
        return itemDAO.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Item findOne(Long id) {
        return itemDAO.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Long id) {
        itemDAO.delete(id);
    }
}
```

SpecificationDigitalDAO и SpecificationDAO наследуются от JpaRepository.

Comment: Ну вот зачем нам скрины ваших форм? Вы лучше бы положили скрины таблиц со связями для наглядности

Comment: @Victor связи таблиц видны из аннотаций маппинга.

Comment: Попробуйте в ManyToMany указать параметр cascade. В простейшем случае @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}). Хотя в данном случае JPA и так должна справляться, по крайней мере если спецификации не изменялись. Но всегда имеются разночтения стандартов и я не знаю что ещё туда привносит прослойка из spring (JpaRepository от него?). Например EclipseLink без оболочки spring с такой задачей вроде справлялся.

Comment: @Sergey да, я знаю. Но я же и написал "для наглядности". Я визуал и мне проще и быстрее с ориентироваться по схеме а не маппингу. И все же схема куда полезнее нежели скрины форм